# When using Django's Prefetch object, it makes one query per related object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I've been developing with Django for a while. I am familiar with `prefetch_related` and was noticing some strange behavior today when working with `Prefetch` objects. I was under the impression that a queryset executed with `prefetch_related` would make 2 queries, 1 for the parent objects, and another for the children filtering on the parent object ids.

However, when I print the queries being executed using `pretch_related` with a `Prefetch` object, I noticed that one query was being made per related object which diminishes the desired effect of `prefetch_related`.

Can anyone fill me in to why this is happening based on the following code and returned SQL.

```
Schedule.objects.prefetch_related("shifts")

# SQL returned 

[{"sql": 'SELECT "schedule"."id" FROM "schedule" LIMIT 21', "time": "0.033"},
    {
        "sql": 'SELECT "shift"."id" FROM "shift" WHERE "shift"."shift_id" IN (1, 2) ORDER BY "shift"."order" ASC',
        "time": "0.062",
    }
]
```

The above is what I expected

Now the problem queryset

```
Schedule.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        "shifts",
        queryset=Shift.objects.filter(
            state__in=[States.COMPLETED, States.PENDING]
        )
        .order_by("assigned_at", "priority", "order")
        .only("id"),
    )
).only("id")

# SQL returned 

    [{"sql": 'SELECT "schedule"."id" FROM "schedule" LIMIT 21', "time": "0.009"},
    {
        "sql": 'SELECT "shift"."id" FROM "shift" WHERE ("shift"."state" IN (\'completed\', \'pending\') AND "shift"."shift_id" IN (1, 2)) ORDER BY "shift"."assigned_at" ASC, "shift"."priority" ASC, "shift"."order" ASC',
        "time": "0.015",
    },
    {
        "sql": 'SELECT "shift"."id", "shift"."shift_id" FROM "shift" WHERE "shift"."id" = 2 LIMIT 21',
        "time": "0.004",
    },
    {
        "sql": 'SELECT "shift"."id", "shift"."shift_id" FROM "shift" WHERE "shift"."id" = 3 LIMIT 21',
        "time": "0.002",
    },
    {
        "sql": 'SELECT "shift"."id", "shift"."shift_id" FROM "shift" WHERE "shift"."id" = 1 LIMIT 21',
        "time": "0.002",
    }]
```

Any help understanding why the prefetch object is causing the prefetch_related function to make one query per related object would be great.

Comment: How did you access the child element after you get the schedule instance？ In my experience, it would affect the query statement.

Comment: these SQL statements are just from executing the queryset, not even accessing the child elements at this point. I executed the querysets and printed out `connection.queries`

Comment: I guess the `only("id")` statement at the end was mistook by the django ORM, could you try it out without it:
`Schedule.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        "shifts",
        queryset=Shift.objects.filter(
            state__in=[States.COMPLETED, States.PENDING]
        )
        .order_by("assigned_at", "priority", "order")
        .only("id"),
    ).all()`

Comment: Adding the foreign key field to the `.only('id', 'schedule_id')` fixed the issue. Interesting behavior. Thank you for prompting me to change that. Going to look into what's going on and if that is the intended behavior. Probably important to note, I am using django 3.2.18

Comment: Really weird situation, but glad you work it out! 